# jQuery post - why there are duplicate requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {

        var site_url = $("#site_url").val();
        var post_url = site_url+"index.php/ajax/get_more_users";
        $("#loading_more_users").show();
        var users_page = $("#users_page").val();


        //alert("y");
        $.post(post_url, {'page': users_page}, function(data){              
                //alert("x");
            $("#loading_more_users").hide();
            $("#left_members_collumn").append(data);
            $("#users_page").val(eval(Number(users_page)+1));


        });

   }
});
```

Anyone can tell me why the $.post are executed once, twice or three times when I scroll bottom? I get the duplicate content. The main function is executed fine, but I don't know why there are multiples ajax requests.

Thank you.

Comment: The `$.post` can trigger as many times as it wants within those 10 pixels that you gave it. Also, why are you using `eval`?

Comment: try using innerHeight() instead of height()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll is firing multiple times with criteria that satisfy your if condition.  What you can do to prevent this is set a bool to indicate your are posting, so you don't post twice:

```
var isPosting = false;
$(window).scroll(function () { 

    if (!isPosting && $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
        isPosting = true;
        var site_url = $("#site_url").val();
        var post_url = site_url+"index.php/ajax/get_more_users";
        $("#loading_more_users").show();
        var users_page = $("#users_page").val();


        //alert("y");
        $.post(post_url, {'page': users_page}, function(data){              
                //alert("x");
            $("#loading_more_users").hide();
            $("#left_members_collumn").append(data);
            $("#users_page").val(eval(Number(users_page)+1));
            isPosting = false;

        });

   }
});
```

Comment: I'd remove `eval()` as well. It's not doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

YOu will execute the ajax request every time you scroll because you bind this functions to `$(window).scroll()` function. If your `if` return true, then you will execute the `ajax request`.

To evict this, you can use the function `one`function from jquery:

```
$(window).one('scroll', function () { 

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {

        var site_url = $("#site_url").val();
        var post_url = site_url+"index.php/ajax/get_more_users";
        $("#loading_more_users").show();
        var users_page = $("#users_page").val();


        //alert("y");
        $.post(post_url, {'page': users_page}, function(data){              
            //alert("x");
            $("#loading_more_users").hide();
            $("#left_members_collumn").append(data);
            $("#users_page").val(eval(Number(users_page)+1));
        });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. There are still many $.post requests to the server and I'm receiving duplicate content. I don't know why the $.post() will executed many times. The server side part works perfectly, I've tested it without ajax request. If, inside $.post() I write a alert(), it will be called many times. Why?